# Different ways to calculate magnetic field of a segment of current

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

Given a segment of current $I$ of length $L$, we want to calculate $\vec{B}$ on a plane that is perpendicular bisector of the segment.

From the Biot-Savart law, $\vec{B}$ depends on $L$ and $R$ (the location's distance to the segment).

But we can still use Ampere's law, due to symmetricity: then $\vec{B}$ only depends on $R$.

Do I miss anything here, especially the penetrating current in Ampere's law?

Comment: A segment being of finite length, there's no translational invariance alongside it, so $\vec{B}$ will depend on $R$ *and* $L$, making Ampere's law impractical (although still correct, technically).

Answer (score 0):

In a  book (Japanese, authors: Goto and Yamasaki), the analytical formula is shown as follows,
$$
\Delta B_{12}=\frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi l}\int_{\theta_1}^{\pi-\theta_2}\text{sin}\theta d\theta
=\frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi l}\left[-\text{cos}\theta\right]_{\theta_1}^{\pi-\theta_2}
=\frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi l}(\text{cos}\theta_1+\text{cos}\theta_2).
$$[image: calculate B from line segment]

Sorry, notations differ from you. $R_1$, $R_2$  and $P$ are points; $l$ is the distance.
The orientation of $\Delta B_{12}$ is perpendicular to the plane of the figure to conform to Ampere's law.